# Image with border radius + border color not working on Chrome/Safari iOS

Tags: ios, css

I'm trying to work out why an image with a circle border radius and a white border color isn't working on Chrome/Safari on iOS. It works on my desktop.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like, along with my HTML/CSS:

**Screenshot:** http://i46.tinypic.com/29z61c4.jpg

**HTML:**

```
<div class="span4">
        <img class="img-circle" src="assets/img/subfeatured1.jpg">
        <h3>Feature 1</h3>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">View details »</a></p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img-circle {
  width: 70%;
  border: 10px solid white;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
       -moz-border-radius: 50%;       
            border-radius: 50%;

       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,1);  
          -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,1);  
               box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,1);

     -moz-background-clip: padding;  
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;  
          background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Comment: I replaced the border with a box shadow and it seemed to fix the issue:

`box-shadow: 0 0 0 9px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,1);`

Comment: You should post that as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser version is old that's why this problem occur. and you doesn't need to use `background-clip` property.

check this, <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wEGDY/)**</kbd>

#### HTML

```
<img class="img-circle" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-J_QabuviUDk/UEdgMt2AvfI/AAAAAAAAEIQ/yPc1XekoSnE/s1600/800px-Rectangle_example.svg.png">
```

#### CSS

```
.img-circle {
  width: 80%;
  border: 10px solid white;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
       -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
            border-radius: 50%;

       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,1);  
          -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,1);  
               box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

`Chrome` and `Safari` vender prefix same so i think its working on safari, I'm not sure 100%.